# MySql delete from select with multiple column?

Tags: mysql

The following

```
delete from child N
where parent_id in
(select parent_id , count(*) c
from parent
group by other_attribute  having c > 1 )
```

understandably returns

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

How do you fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select the count in the subquery.  Just use the count explicitly in the `HAVING` clause:

```
delete from child N
where parent_id in
(
    select parent_id
    from parent
    group by other_attribute
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to be

```
delete from child 
where parent_id in (
select parent_id 
 from parent   
group by other_attribute  
having count(*) > 1 )
```

(OR)

Make it a `JOIN` query saying

```
delete child 
from child
join (    
select parent_id 
from parent   
group by other_attribute  
having count(*) > 1 ) xxx on child.parent_id = xxx.parent_id;
```